# Domain name is syntactically invalid

Tags: server, dns, email, mail

I trying to send e-mail via exim . when i try to send mail to mail.ru i got an error . What should i do? host domain on my machine?  and why it is 
syntactically invalid. How should i reconfigure my exim server to send e-mail. By the way it works with gmail but letter go into spam

> R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (-45): SMTP error from remote mail
>   server after MAIL FROM: SIZE=1336: host
>   mxs.mail.ru [94.100.180.150]: 421 Problem resolving DNS for domain
>   gen3212@gmail.com (Domain name is syntactically invalid)